# How to get more than 100 fetched data result from gatsby wordpress

Tags: gatsby

I want to fetch 300 WordPress post using gatsby. but I don't know how to increase the number of per page that accepts per time.
this is how I fetch data from WordPress using gatsby.

```
   resolve: 'gatsby-source-WordPress', 
options: {

  baseUrl: '******',
perPage: 1000,

  hostingWPCOM: true,

  protocol: 'https',

  useACF: true,
  auth: {
    wpcom_app_clientSecret: "******",
    wpcom_app_clientId: "******",
    wpcom_user: "******",
    wpcom_pass: "******",

  },
.......
},
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check [Gatsby WordPress Source documentation](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-source-wordpress), you can see that there is an available option to increase pagination value `perPage`.

So in your `gatsby-config.js`, where you declare your plugin, you can do:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    // ...
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-wordpress",
      options: {
        // ...
        perPage: 1000
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: I made perPage as you did but it creates an error.
..../posts?per_page=1000&page=1
The server response was "400 Bad Request"
Inner exception message: "Invalid parameter(s): per_page"

Comment: Which version of Wordpress do you use?

Comment: The version of my WordPress site is 5.3.2

Comment: I think you have to show us how you fetch Wordpress data. Please edit your question